# Can anyone explain what's the issue?

Tags: node.js, npm

The error I am getting:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:85
  let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
  ^^^



 SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) 
  not yet supported outside strict mode
```

Comment: That's pretty clear though... strict mode should be active in order to use `let`. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp

Comment: That won't solve the underlying issue which is a node version issue. This would just add a bandaid to the original issue. This version issue tends to occur to Linux users.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your Node version. This will globally update Node and npm and install the stable version:

**n** Helps with version handling.

About **n**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/n

```
sudo npm install -g npm
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

If that doesn't work try:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/11.10.1/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

This will install the latest node version and create a symbolic link.

Comment: Thanks, SO newbie here. Will try to get better with my responses.

Comment: Cool, welcome to Stack Overflow!  The way I usually think of it is that you're essentially writing a reference, not just for this particular question, but for future folks with the same or similar question.  Any time you can explain to someone how to solve their own problem, you're teaching them to teach others, while at the same time writing a good reference for future visitors so they don't even need to ask the question... as you've already answered it.

Comment: Brad, you're absolutely right. When we Google problems we want to see great responses, not mediocre SO responses that aren't helpful - or insightful. I certainly originally provided a lazy answer - partly because I responded with my phone which makes it a pain. However, SO needs useful and clear answers, so I'll be more aware of that and make better contributions.